# Trying to understand buffer-overflow and setuid. I don't get privileges

Tags: c, linux, root, buffer-overflow, setuid

I am trying to understand about buffer overflow and setuid. I use this source :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char prog[]="/bin/ls -hal";
    char in[8]={0};
    printf("Name of a dir to list : ");
    gets(in);
    char *cmd;
    cmd=malloc(strlen(prog)+strlen(in)+2);
    strcat(cmd, prog);
    strcat(cmd, " ");
    strcat(cmd, in);
    return system(cmd);
}
```

After compiling it, I change the owner with :

```
sudo chown root:root a.out
```

I set the rights :

```
sudo chmod 4755 a.out
```

Now the a.out looks like :

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 7544 mai 01:24 a.out
```

I launch it with my current user (not root), and with ps aux | grep a.out :

```
root 4656 0.0 0.0 4084 684 pts/0 S+ 01:52 0:00 ./a.out
```

So that is ok. 
If my input is :

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/bin/bash;
```

I get a new shell, but I am not root on it I am logged with my current user, and I don't understand why. Because the owner is root, and I put the setuid so the new bash will be launched with root's rights no ?

Comment: a buffer overflow on char in[8]={0}; I put severals "a" and I overwrite /bin/ls by a /bin/bash. On my computer I have to write 16 "a" and /bin/bash;

Comment: `bash` detects if it's being run setuid and drops the privileges.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74527/setuid-bit-seems-to-have-no-effect-on-bash

Comment: Is there a solution to get a root shell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setuid flag on an executable problem sets the euid (effective UID).  Your uid, and not your euid are passed through to child processes.  Before you call the `system()` command do

`setuid(geteuid());`